Why does isabelle's preorder requires to provide less _and_ less_eq
Isabelle's preorder class requires providing both less_eq and less:

class ord =
  fixes less_eq :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"
    and less :: "'a ⇒ 'a ⇒ bool"

class preorder = ord +
  assumes less_le_not_le: "x < y ⟷ x ≤ y ∧ ¬ (y ≤ x)"
  and order_refl [iff]: "x ≤ x"
  and order_trans: "x ≤ y ⟹ y ≤ z ⟹ x ≤ z"


--- https://www.isa-afp.org/sessions/hol/#Orderings.html#Orderings.preorder.intro_of_class|fact

But it's really annoying. I have a relation a <= relation and I would like to prove that's it's a preorder, but Isabelle forces me to define a corresponding <. I could, but it's (in my case, a lot of) extra work that I don't need.
Why does Isabelle force me to do this? And is there a nice way to derive a dummy < from a given <=. Should I define my own preorder that just requires <=?
There is a local called partial_preorder which only requires <=, like I need, but it's not a class.

My guess is because there is a functional difference between <= and <. If you're doing something mathematically, there's a major difference between something being less than or equal to a value and something being less than a value. Using 10 as an example, it's vastly different when something is required to be less than 10 (10 would be invalid) and less than or equal to, where 10 would be valid. Isabelle doesn't know that you'll never need to know the difference.


Isabelle forces me to define a corresponding <. I could, but it's (in my case, a lot of) extra work that I don't need.

Technically, the < is no real extra work, is it?
The class axiom ‹x < y ⟷ x ≤ y ∧ ¬ (y ≤ x)› does not really leave choice on the implementation of <.
Let us consider the following minimal example of two-component nat vectors with pointwise comparison:
datatype nat_vec2 =
  Vec nat nat

fun nat_vec_lesseq where
  ‹nat_vec_lesseq (Vec m1 m2) (Vec n1 n2) ⟷ m1 ≤ n1 ∧ m2 ≤ n2›

Instantiating it as a preorder requires just a few lines, where we explicate which functions should play the roles of ≤ and < (for which
we have to use the magic names less_eq_nat_vec2 and less_nat_vec2), and then prove the class axioms:
instantiation nat_vec2 :: preorder
begin

definition ‹less_eq_nat_vec2 ≡ nat_vec_lesseq›
definition ‹less_nat_vec2 m n ≡ nat_vec_lesseq m n ∧ ¬ nat_vec_lesseq n m›

instance proof
  fix m n::nat_vec2
  show ‹(m < n) = (m ≤ n ∧ ¬ n ≤ m)›
    unfolding less_nat_vec2_def less_eq_nat_vec2_def by blast
next
  fix m::nat_vec2
  show ‹m ≤ m›
    unfolding less_eq_nat_vec2_def by (cases m, simp)
next
  fix m n p::nat_vec2
  assume ‹m ≤ n› ‹n ≤ p›
  thus ‹m ≤ p›
    unfolding less_eq_nat_vec2_def by (cases m, cases n, cases p, auto)
qed

end

You are right that some boilerplate is needed for <.
But it is only one line for the definition, and two lines for the first case of the instance proof!
And these lines are virtually the same for every preorder one would define. (One just needs to adapt the magic variable names for different instantiations..) The other cases (reflexivity and transitivity) might on the other hand be way more involved, depending on the order used.
So there is not much point in working around providing < because it does in fact not add a lot of extra work.
In particular, defining one's own preorder to work around the issue, would definitely entail MUCH more work because it disconnects the theory from all the conveniences of the build-in ordering classes. (E.g. derived min, max, etc.)
Shortly answering the question in the title on the design decision behind ord:
I assume that the nice global infix notion for < depends on it being part of the class interface and not being defined as a derived constant for orders (as the constant names min and max are for example).
But I never really understood the precise rules for notation “inheritance” in Isabelle; so this is just a guess.
